# Execute command after seconds (without sleep)

Tags: command-line, shell, sleep

How can I run a command after X seconds without sleep. Or with sleep but without the shell just wait for the response of that command?

I used this but it didn't work

```
sleep 5 ; ls > a.txt
```

I need to run it in background. I try not to have to run it in a script
I try to run `ls` after 5 seconds, and shell does not just wait for the end of the sleep

Comment: Why does it not work without the shell? Which error do you get? Are you passing it the full path? Do you know which part parses the `;` ?

Comment: in this way the shell will block 5 seconds and then run the command., the shell to be stalled I do not need that.

Comment: Then you either need to start it in a script in the background, or in a sub-shell.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A more concise way of writing what Hennes suggested is

```
(sleep 5; echo foo) &
```

---

Alternatively, if you need more than a few seconds, you could use [`at`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_at.htm). There are three ways of giving a command to `at`:

1. Pipe it:

   ```
   $ echo "ls > a.txt" | at now + 1 min
   warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
   job 3 at Thu Apr  4 20:16:00 2013
   ```
2. Save the command you want to run in a text file, and then pass that file to `at`:

   ```
   $ echo "ls > a.txt" > cmd.txt
   $ at now + 1 min < cmd.txt
   warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
   job 3 at Thu Apr  4 20:16:00 2013
   ```
3. You can also pass `at` commands from STDIN:

   ```
   $ at now + 1 min
   warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
   at> ls
   ```

   Then, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to exit the `at` shell. The `ls` command will be run in one minute.

You can give very precise times in the format of `[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss]`, as in

```
$ at -t 201412182134.12 < script.sh
```

This will run the script `script.sh` at 21:34 and 12 seconds on the 18th of December 2014. So, in theory, you could use `at` to run something five seconds in the future. However, that is kinda like using a tank to swat a fly, and Hennes's suggestion is better.

Comment: I kept messing with `$(sleep 5; echo foo) &` I am not sure why I thought I needed a $ in front of that, but with my syntax wrong I just posted the longer (and more understandable) version. ( command_for_in_new_shell ) is shorter though.

Comment: @Hennes and I blatantly ripped off your very good idea (which I upvoted). All I did was reformat it to be shorter, all credit for the actual thinking bits is yours :).

Comment: Is there any way to use `at` with a delay in seconds?

Comment: @NicHartley no. Use a specific time (e.g. `at 21:43`) if that's what you want, or just do something simple like `sleep 4 && command` to run `command` after 4 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

You can work around it by starting a shell or a script in the background.

Example:

```
/bin/sh -c "sleep 5 ; echo foo" &
[1] 63791
>                               Active shell prompt here

foo                             5 second later output appears.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would start apache web server after 4 hours. *I fully understand that you want it without the command `sleep`.*  But I used a different approach about keeping the command running even after logging-out using the command `nohup`.  Don't forget to add  the `&` character at the end. It's part of the whole command below. It helps in making the command run detached from the command line prompt.

```
nohup sleep 14400 && service apache2 start &
```